# Javascript default function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I try to understand javascript in depth, i have achieved what i wanted to do, but i'm pretty sure there is a better way.

I have this code :

```
var props = {
  val: 'foo',
  test: function() {
    console.log(this.val);
  }
}

function testFactory() {
  var myFunc = function () {
    myFunc.test();
  };
  myFunc.__proto__ = props;
  return myFunc;
}
```

It's allow me to have a function with properties :

```
var test = testFactory();
test(); // "foo"
test.val = 'bar';
test(); // "bar";
```

The problem is that a new "`myFunc`" is recreated everytime i run "`testFactory()`".
I'm pretty sure i can do this **in a better way** ?!

Thak you in advance.

**EDIT**

After your answers and comments :

```
function testFactory() {
  var myFunc = function () {
    myFunc.test();
  };
  Object.assign(myFunc, props);
  return myFunc;
}
```

Comment: what's your definition of "a better way"?

Comment: Are you sure you want to override the prototype of a function? Also, what else is a factory doing than creating new instances?

Comment: No, there's no way around creating a new `myFunc` every time. Because apparently that is what you want `testFactory` to do, create a new object that is a function.

Comment: Okay will stick to that then. Will just use "Object.assign" instead of replacing the whole prototype. Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you don't want to do this:

```
myFunc.__proto__ = props;
```

...because that will make the function lose the features it inherits from `Function.prototype`, like `call`, `apply`, and `bind`. (`__proto__` is also a [browser-only extension](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.prototype.__proto__) to JavaScript; if you really wanted to change the prototype of something after constructing it, which usually suggests a design problem, the proper way would be to use [`Reflect.setPrototypeOf`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-reflect.setprototypeof). [This is an ES2015 feature.])

To assign properties to a function, just assign properties to it:

```
function foo() {
    console.log("I'm foo");
}
foo.bar = "xyz";
foo(); // "I'm foo"
console.log(foo.bar); // "xyz"
```

Functions are objects, and like any other object, you can put your own properties on them.

If you want to assign a bunch of properties, in ES2015 you can use [`Object.assign`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.assign):

```
Object.assign(foo, {
    bar: "xyz",
    baz: 123
});
```

(In pre-ES2015 code, you could just use a loop.)